# What is the meaning of this code in Java?

Tags: java

I was going through some of the questions online and I came across this code. I couldn't understand the meaning of this particular line of code. Please can anyone explain me the meaning of this line of code.

So, there are two classes Student class and Course class. Each class has its own setters and getters. Now, there is this one output statement which is something like this:

`System.out.println("I like " + student2.getCourse().getCourseCode());`

**bdw student2 is an object of the Studentclass

The part that i am confused is `student2.getCourse().getCourseCode()`
It looks like two methods are somehow linked or something. What is the meaning of this line. Any article or suggestions is really appreiciated. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that it's called method chaining. `student2.getCourse()` returns a Course object, which then has the `getCourseCode()` called immediately on it.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted? If i don't understand something, Am i not even allowed to ask in StackOverflow!

Comment: I don't know why it was down-voted, and down-voters (or up-voters) are not required to state why. Perhaps it is because it is a very basic issue, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Melissa I think your question was down voted, because is is not clear what you have tried on your own to understand the problem. SO rules state that a minimum effort must have been undertaken before the question is put here.

Comment: @luksch:- I generally put my code in SO but i was reading this code online and the author din't even explain the meaning of that line of code. I tried it in my own way to solve the problem and it worked but i was curious to know the meaning of that particular line of code. So, i dint have any option as i was completely clueless about it. I dint even know it was called "Method chaining". Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`student2.getCourse()` returns a course. It is possible to call `getCourseCode()` on a course. This is an example of *method chaining*.

The equivalent code is:

```
Course tempVar = student2.getCourse();
System.out.println("I like" + tempVar.getCourseCode());
```

As you learn more programming, you will find this to be consistent. A variable declared `Course` is clearly a course, but the result of a method called `Course.getCourse` also is a course, and you can use it as a course (including calling the methods of course (no pun intended)).

Comment: :- Thanks a lot for such an amazing explanation.

Comment: @Melissa No problem, please mark this answer with the check mark if it has completely answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println("I like " + student2.getCourse().getCourseCode());`

I've formatting the line above fro reference. Stundent2.getCourse() returns the course that the student is enrolled in (presumably). getCourseCode() is then called on the course that was returned previously

Comment: @Melissa It is good practice here on SO to thank helpful people by upvoting their answers and accepting the best answer, if it truly answers your question.

Comment: @luksch Good advice, although he doesn't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: @luksch:- I dint have enough reputation to upvote.